# Conectar phpMyAdmin desde maquina virtual linux CentOS 7 a la maquina principal

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7

Buenas tengo un problema al intentar extraer datos del phpmyadmin que se encuentra en mi maquina virtual Linux CentOS 7 y mostrarlos en una lista cabe resaltar que tengo acceso a phpmyadmin desde mi equipo anfitrión con mi usuario root del equipo CentOS 7 el cual cuenta con una contraseña el problema es imprimir los datos de la misma en una pagina web en php   otro punto a resaltar es que soy nuevo con php y phpmyadmin

código de conexión empleado en php:

```
<?php
    $servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $clave="1234";
    $baseDeDatos="formulario";

    $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);º

    if(!$enlace){
        echo "Error en la conexión con el servidor";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un truco sencilloque puedes utilizar para abrir un puerto en el *host* para que conecte con un puerto en el *guest* (si el guest no es visible por la red) es abrir un *ssh tunnel* si en el host tienes un servicio de ssh funcionando. Digamos que queremos conectar el puerto 8888 del *host* con el puerto 9999 del *guest*. Desde el guest corres esto:

```
ssh -R 8888:localhost:9999 usuariodelhost@ip-del-host
```

Con eso un servicio que en el guest está en el puerto 9999 va a ser accesible a través del puerto 8888 del host.